# Rails 5 api enable public folder browsable

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-api, ruby-on-rails-5

I created rails api with Rails 5.0.0.rc1 and Ruby 2.3.0
I need to make "public" folder under application path is browsable

I added the below line into config/application.rb file

```
config.public_file_server.enabled = true
```

But my api could not browse public folder at link

http://localhost:3000/public/404.html

or http://localhost:3000/public

How can I do that
Thanks

Comment: what web server are you using?

Comment: Hi @victorsosa! I am using unicorn

Comment: HI, I meant if you are using NGINX or Apache?

Answer (score 0):

On Nginx you need to set you location on autoindex to see the files in the directory using you browser.

youNginx.conf

```
location / {
  autoindex on;
}
```

> config.public_file_server.enabled configures Rails to serve static
>   files from the public directory. This option defaults to true, but in
>   the production environment it is set to false because the server
>   software (e.g. NGINX or Apache) used to run the application should
>   serve static files instead. If you are running or testing your app in
>   production mode using WEBrick (it is not recommended to use WEBrick in
>   production) set the option to true. Otherwise, you won't be able to
>   use page caching and request for files that exist under the public
>   directory.

Comment: Thanks @victorsosa